# hadoop mapreduce Mapper reading incorrect value from text file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a mapreduce program to process a text file append a string to each line.The problem i am facing is that the text value coming in map method of the mapper is incorrect .

Whenever a line in the file is lesser than previous line , few characters are automatically appended to the line to make the line length equal to previous read line.

Map method params as below

```
*@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {*
```

I am logging the value inside the map method and observing this behavior.
Any pointers?

Code Snippet

```
Driver

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.set("CLIENT_ID", "Test");
        Job job = Job.getInstance(configuration, JOB_NAME);
        job.setJarByClass(JobDriver.class);
        job.setMapperClass(AdwordsMapper.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, GzipCodec.class);

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);


Mapper

public class AdwordsMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String textLine = new String(value.getBytes());

        textLine = new StringBuffer(textLine).append(",")
                .append(context.getConfiguration().get("CLIENT_ID")).toString();
        context.write(new Text(""), new Text(textLine));

    }

}
```

Comment: can you post your code.

Comment: Code snippet for driver and mapper class added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of my knowledge ,the problem with in your mapper is getBytes();

instead of this

```
   String textLine = new String(value.getBytes());
```

try it.

```
   String textLine = value.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks Sravan. That fixed the issue. One more query regarding the output key. When i put empty text, there is a tab character coming in ouput file. Is there a way to specify a key without generating any additional characters?

Comment: Used NullWritable for the key. Also i have multiple files in input folder.Currently only one output file is generated after processing all input files.Can we generate 1 output file per input file

Comment: Used file input path based output riting by overriding setup method in mapper.things are fine now!!!